# Error in deploying SQL Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to deploy [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5h3sxyxyiu2ejn/TestSQLAdapter.adapter?dl=0) SQL adapter into MobileFirst Console V8.0.0.00-20170220-1900, but it is failing with following error:

```
[8/18/17 16:54:23:861 CDT] 000fed6b AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/18/17 16:54:23:861 CDT] 000fed6b ServiceProxy  2 com.ibm.mfp.admin.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy service Caught exception
                                 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://10.80.25.54:9081/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters?asynch=true
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy.service(ServiceProxy.java:188)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.ui.servlet.ConsoleServicesServlet.service(ConsoleServicesServlet.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://10.80.25.54:9081/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters?asynch=true
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy.service(ServiceProxy.java:180)
    ... 19 more

[8/18/17 16:54:23:861 CDT] 000fed6b DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
```

Comment: The issue appears to be with runtime synchronization. I deployed the adapter no my local server ( 20170426 build) and it works fine.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Try restarting the server and redeploying the adapter. I do not have the same iFix level as yours to test. If possible try upgrading the server